# Chrome devtools debugger: see scope variables at different places in call stack

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

When I click at different locations in the call stack, the context variables listed under Scope don't change. I'm new to JS and am familar with using tools like PDB and PyCharm for Python where I can see local variables at different places in the call stack. Is there a convenient way to do this in Chrome without stepping into each context one by one?

[image: chrome screenshot]

Comment: For completeness please add the version of Chrome (in case this behavior will change in the future).

Comment: It probably means there's a source map applied so the displayed stack is a "fake".

Comment: Please add screenshots of the other (two) stack level(s) and also try to reproduce this with a simpler reproducer (three functions calling each other, declaring parameters/local variables). **edit** your post to add details.